# Excel VLOOKUP multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I want to pull through 6 columns of information from 1 sheet to another sheet on excel when I type a customer name. I've tried multiple different array and vlookup formulas and nothing is working for me. Excel newbie so please be kind :)

To explain further, I have a customer database with important information needed to process their orders. I want this information which is across 6 excel columns to pull through to my main order log when I type in the customers name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the formulas you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 365 you will have access to XLOOKUP. It might solve your problem.

Trying to figure out what you have in mind I created this simple example. Sheet 1 would be your data base, sheet to the results page.

[image]

Here in sheet 2 I'm using XLOOKUP to look at the customer name in column A, and return the values from columns A to G.

[image]

Hopefully, you have Office 365 and this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This is pretty much exactly the use case for `VLOOKUP`.

Let's say you have two tables; one's your orders table and the other your customer database.

Orders:

[image: orders sheet]

And, on another sheet/tab, the Customers database. Note that I've given this table a name that we'll use later:

[image: Customers database]

Now, I understand that what you'd like to be able to do is type in a customer name in the orders table and have the customer data pull in automatically. The important bit here is that you have [table-ized these tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-table-in-excel-bf0ce08b-d012-42ec-8ecf-a2259c9faf3f), which means Excel will automatically pull down formulas when you add a new row, like so:

[image: adding an order]

You see I've just typed in a new order number, without having put in the customer name yet, and columns `C:E` have automatically populated.

This is the formula in `C3`: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Customer Name]],Customers,2,FALSE),"Customer not found")`

Let's give that a look. Start with the lookup. `=VLOOKUP([@[Customer Name]],Customers,2,FALSE)`

`VLOOKUP` takes four arguments:

1. What to look for
2. Where to look (has to be first column of a given range)
3. Which column to the right of 'where to look' to report back
4. put `FALSE` here (the usage of this parameter is for another discussion)

So you're saying, look for `[@[Customer Name]]` (this is Excel table notation for 'the data on this line in the Customer Name column in this table') in the first column in `Customers` (the entire data range of the Customers table) and give me the value from the `2`nd column of that range (in this case, favorite color).

So you set up the formulas such that `C3` asks for column `2`, `C4` asks for column `3`, etc.

Then you surround it with an `IFERROR` so you don't get an ugly `#N/A` if you have a typo or data error.

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`XLOOKUP()`, as in `BradR`'s answer is the simplest though I suspect that using it in a log I suspect you'd like it more like:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,  Sheet2!A2:A4,  Sheet2!B2:G4)
```

so that the six columns of data appear on the same line as the name/ID.

If, though, you wish to use `VLOOKUP()`, you would so it with a formula like the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,  Sheet2!A2:G4,  {2,3,4,5,6,7},  FALSE)
```

I put it that way to show the "array constant" in use, but anything that would produce it is acceptable. For instance, `SEQUENCE(1,6,2,1)` would do the same and its parameters could each be built from formulas while a literal array constant cannot be created dynamically.

Caveats:

1. `VLOOKUP()` will only use the first parameter that results in an array constant that it finds in the formula. So if you use an array constant for the lookup values, it will take only the first element of the later array constant. In this case, that means it would return only a single column's data, not all six. However, it's usually OK since what one does most with the first parameter (other than to use it straightforwardly) is to concatenate multiple inputs, not to search for more than one possible lookup value at a time. (Like:  `"Jim" & " S. " & "Smith"` but not so much `{"Jim","Joe","Jill"}`.) So not ordinarily a problem.
2. If it is possible for there to be more than one entry of the name/ID value, only `FILTER()` will let you have all of them using a function to do it. (You CAN build such a thing other ways, but via a simple, more or less, single function? No.) Related is that ALL the main three single result lookups have ways to search from the end (so getting the last instance rather than the first) though `XLOOKUP()` is by far the simplest to do it with).

Comment: I appreciate what you do but there is zero chance OP can get anything out of this answer. I can barely follow some of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the SUMPRODUCT function, enter the formula and drag and drop to right:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$K$2)*($B$1:$G$1=L1),$B$2:$G$5)
```

[image]

Comment: this is not extensible as presented. formula needs updating to `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$K2)*($B$1:$G$1=L$1),$B$2:$G$5)`. Really elegant solution though

Comment: This won't work for non-numeric data, though, will it?