# Selecting rows to match up to another list on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm an Excel novice and I'm trying to select the genes in column C based on Column A and to match up all the info in columns C to H to the corresponding row based on column A

[image: Spreadsheet]

Column A is a set list and I am hoping to get column C to H to match that with blanks when a gene from column A is not in column C.

Comment: Look at this very similar question and the respective answers: https://superuser.com/questions/1730237/excel-vlookup-multiple-columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the Column A to a new Column or a new Worksheet. For example copy Column A to Column L, then enter the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$C$2:$H$12,COLUMN(A1),FALSE),"")
```

Then drag right and down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try an IF Statement.

Since you are not used to using Excel, you can click on Formulas and find the IF/IF Else Formulas and Excel will 'walk' you through how to use it and it will show an example output in the box, so you can try your formula to see if it works:

```
IF(A1-100 = "GENETIC_SEQ", C1 = "Found", C1="").
```

This formula will check A1 through 100 (change it to suit ur needs) for the GENETIC_SEQ, but you **must** use double-quotes like I did above or Excel will not read it correctly.

- If the value of A# equals the SEQ, then in C1 it will print "Found"
- If False and A# doesn't equal SEQ, it will leave C# empty.

P.S. After you write a formula in one box, you can highlight it, click and drag the bottom right corner down the column (A) to 'copy' the formula to the other cells in a "smart" format, aka it will change A1/C1 to A2/C2.

---

After reading the comment above, that user is right, one of the "LOOKUP" functions will work better than IF/ELSE. You can click on the *fx* button to open the functions menu and type "lookup" in the search box and choose, based on the description, which function you think will work best.